# Using RSA key containers as a key generator for AES - can I do this in a better way?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, aes, rsa

I have been tasked with creating an internal document management system at my place of work. A requirement of the task is to encrypt documents imported into the system and only decrypt them when request by the end user. Also, the end user wont know the password/key for decryption, the system must fully handle the encryption and decryption on its own.

I wanted to use AES (no real reason, just seemed like a good option) so I started looking into how I could generate and store secure keys for AES. I couldn't find much in the way of implementation methods, just a lot of what not to do. The only decent way I found was using .NET Key Containers (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-store-asymmetric-keys-in-a-key-container) but its intended for asymmetric keys.

So I started playing with it and below is a working sample of using RSA in combination with AES:

```
    public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data, byte[] salt)
    {
        byte[] encrypted;
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes deriveBytes;

        // Sanity
        if (data == null || data.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
        if (salt == null || salt.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("salt");

        // Create AES object
        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(GetKeyFromContainer(), salt, MAX_ITERATIONS);
            aes.Key = deriveBytes.GetBytes(32);
            aes.IV = salt;

            ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                }
                encrypted = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        return encrypted;
    }


    public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data, byte[] salt)
    {
        byte[] decrypted;
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes deriveBytes;

        // Sanity
        if (data == null || data.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
        if (salt == null || salt.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("salt");

        // Create AES object
        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(GetKeyFromContainer(), salt, MAX_ITERATIONS);
            aes.Key = deriveBytes.GetBytes(32);
            aes.IV = salt;

            ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data))
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
                    {
                        decrypted = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return decrypted;
    }

    private static byte[] GetKeyFromContainer()
    {
        CspParameters parameters;
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaServiceProvider;

        parameters = new CspParameters();
        parameters.KeyContainerName = KEY_CONTAINER_NAME;

        rsaServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(parameters);

        return Encoding.Default.GetBytes(rsaServiceProvider.ToXmlString(true));
    }
```

So on to the questions:

1. How bad is it to use RSA to generate an asymmetric key to then be used by AES? What are the weaknesses, if any, to this strategy?
2. Is there a better method/algorithm for encrypting/decrypting the imported documents (not AES)?

I am somewhat inexperienced when it comes to cryptography, so any assistance or educational material is very much appreciated.

Comment: Generating keys is easy; just use `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`.  Storing keys can create security issues.  An alternative (I'm not a crypto guy, but): 1) Use RNG-Csp to generate a key 2) Use RSA (and a key container) to encrypt the key, 3) Store the encrypted key wherever you want.  Then it can only be decrypted (and the document decrypted) on a system where the user has access to that key container.  One advantage of this is that every document gets its own key, which makes attacking the crypto _**much**_ harder

Comment: Although this function may work, it is using algorithms and data structures in ways they are not supposed to be used. Using an RSA private key as password is clearly not as intended. You may return that "hey, it works", but please be aware that private keys can be represented in multiple ways. BER encoding may be used or CRT parameters may be left in or out. So in that case the input of PBKDF2 (`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`) may differ and the resulting AES key may be incorrect. A hybrid cryptosystem as Flydog57 proposes is good practice and has many advantages.

Comment: Reading this over, I realized that I never mentioned that I was assuming you were using AES (i.e., when I said _the key_, I meant, "the AES key you will use to encrypt the document"). Another advantage, you can take that encrypted key and prepend to the cipher text document so that you don't need to worry about keeping track of it. *No one* ever sees the key in clear text, so the RSA key is safe, and the AES key is only ever used once

Comment: @Flydog57 Do you perhaps have any references/samples that I could take a look at that outlines the strategy you referred too? I like the hybrid approach, I just couldn't find a clean way to handle it.

Comment: If I get time, I'll provide an answer (it will be the result of cobbling together old code). But, the general idea is to 1) use RNG-CSP to generate a key of the right length, 2) Use the key and AES to encrypt the doc. 3) use a local RSA key container to encrypt that one-time-use AES key. Now you have both the doc and the key as cipher-text. Store them together (say by prepending the key to the doc). To decrypt, the same RSA key container must be available. Tear the key from the document, decrypt the key using RSA. Then decrypt the doc using AES & the decrypted key.

Comment: Oh, you'll also need to store the AES initialization vector (in clear text). So you finished cipher-text "document" will contain three things: The clear-text init vector, the RSA-encrypted key and the AES-encrypted document body.